# How can I get the full fft coefficients by cufft?

Tags: cuda, cufft

I am doing two dimensional fft process by cufft.
Processing type is real to complex, so the size of out array is NX * (NY / 2 + 1) which is non redundant.
But I need the full coefficients containing the redundant ones.
How can i get them all?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert all your real values to complex values.  This is trivial and simply involves providing a zero imaginary value to go along with each real value.

Then do a cufft C2C (complex to complex) transform, which will be of size NX*NY, both on the input size, and the output side.  There will be no reduction for redundancy.

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert Crovella.